# R splitting string values containing columns and simultaneously duplicating other columns while allowing for letter prefix changes

Tags: r

This question relates to an earlier and simpler question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70757973/r-splitting-string-values-containing-columns-and-simultaneously-duplicating-ot). I have a complex dataframe, the result of a join between two separate dataframes, comprising three columns containing alphanumerical values, ID numbers and area codes.

```
df <- data.frame(column1 = c("ab 34, 35, 36", "cb 23", "df 45, 46", "gh 21"),
                 column2 = c("ID_27", "ID_28", "ID_29", "ID_30"),
                 column3 = c("area51", "area52", "area53", "area54"))

df_join <- data.frame(column1 = c("ab 77, cb 35", "df 23, gh 73", "ij 45, kl 46, mn 21"),
                 column2 = c("ID_27", "ID_28", "ID_29"),
                 column3 = c("area51", "area52", "area53"))

df_joined <- rbind(df, df_join)

df_joined

             column1 column2 column3
1       ab 34, 35, 36   ID_27  area51
2               cb 23   ID_28  area52
3           df 45, 46   ID_29  area53
4               gh 21   ID_30  area54
5        ab 77, cb 35   ID_27  area51
6        df 23, gh 73   ID_28  area52
7 ij 45, kl 46, mn 21   ID_29  area53
```

What I would like to do is clean up the first column by removing the commas and the spaces, so that I am left with neatly uniform 4 character values while simultaneously duplicating the values in the other columns. You will also notice that the two letter prefix changes for rows 5-7, the R code has to allow for this. This is the example of what I'm after:

```
new_df
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   column1 column2 column3
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 ab34    ID_27   area51 
 2 ab35    ID_27   area51 
 3 ab36    ID_27   area51 
 4 ab77    ID_27   area51 
 5 cb23    ID_28   area52 
 6 cb35    ID_27   area51 
 7 df23    ID_28   area52 
 8 df45    ID_29   area53 
 9 df46    ID_29   area53 
10 gh21    ID_30   area54 
11 gh73    ID_28   area52 
12 ij45    ID_29   area53 
13 kl46    ID_29   area53 
14 mn21    ID_29   area53
```

The end result doesn't have to be a tibble, and I am working on transforming large dataframes so the code has to be applicable in a general sense. Any ideas? Tidyverse or older methods welcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches. The key function is `mystrsplit`. It first captures characters and digits separately in two columns `prefix` and `digit`, then fills down all the `NA` prefixes using last-observation-carried-forward, and last paste `prefix` and `digit` together. After `mystrsplit`, we use standard data.table operations to bind all rows together.

```
library(data.table)

mystrsplit <- function(x) {
  x[x == ""] <- NA_character_
  x <- stringr::str_match_all(x, "(?<prefix>[a-z]+)? (?<digit>\\d+)")
  lapply(x, function(s) stringr::str_c(tidyr:::fillDown(s[, "prefix"]), s[, "digit"]))
}

setDT(df_joined)[, c(
  list(column1 = unlist(x <- mystrsplit(column1))), 
  lapply(.SD, rep, times = lengths(x))
), .SDcols = -"column1"]
```

Output

```
    column1 column2 column3
 1:    ab34   ID_27  area51
 2:    ab35   ID_27  area51
 3:    ab36   ID_27  area51
 4:    cb23   ID_28  area52
 5:    df45   ID_29  area53
 6:    df46   ID_29  area53
 7:    gh21   ID_30  area54
 8:    ab77   ID_27  area51
 9:    cb35   ID_27  area51
10:    df23   ID_28  area52
11:    gh73   ID_28  area52
12:    ij45   ID_29  area53
13:    kl46   ID_29  area53
14:    mn21   ID_29  area53
```

---

Or in a `tidyverse` way

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mystrsplit <- function(x) {
  x[x == ""] <- NA_character_
  x <- stringr::str_match_all(x, "(?<prefix>[a-z]+)? (?<digit>\\d+)")
  lapply(x, function(s) stringr::str_c(tidyr:::fillDown(s[, "prefix"]), s[, "digit"]))
}

df_joined %>% mutate(column1 = mystrsplit(column1)) %>% unnest(column1)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   column1 column2 column3
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 ab34    ID_27   area51 
 2 ab35    ID_27   area51 
 3 ab36    ID_27   area51 
 4 cb23    ID_28   area52 
 5 df45    ID_29   area53 
 6 df46    ID_29   area53 
 7 gh21    ID_30   area54 
 8 ab77    ID_27   area51 
 9 cb35    ID_27   area51 
10 df23    ID_28   area52 
11 gh73    ID_28   area52 
12 ij45    ID_29   area53 
13 kl46    ID_29   area53 
14 mn21    ID_29   area53
```

Comment: Great! I have a preference for tidyverse, so I like this approach. Would you know how to modify the code in case column1 contained empty strings, e.g. "", or NA values?

Comment: However, when running the original code, I keep getting the "no 'dimnames' attribute when trying to assign to array" error message.

Comment: Very nice solution - Your `mystrsplit` is clever.

Comment: @William_Boot I updated the `mystrsplit`. Now `""` and `NA_character` lead to an explicit entry of `NA` in column 1. I think you get that error for the data.table solution because of `""` in `column1`. The new function should handle that properly.

Comment: +1 for a nice cohesive solution, -1 for using an un-exported function. Maybe `zoo::na.locf()` would do the trick instead of the internal tidyr function?

Comment: I don't have `zoo` installed and I personally want to restrict external dependencies to either `data.table` or `tidyverse` in this case. Also, although that function is not exported, the source code suggests that the dataframe method of `tidyr::fill` calls `tidyr:::vec_fill_fun`, which then calls `tidyr:::fillDown`/`tidyr:::fillUp`, while `tidyr:::vec_fill_fun` only does a `switch`. In this sense, when we use `tidyr::fill`, the workhorses for each column are really just `tidyr:::fillDown` or `tidyr:::fillUp`. It's safe to use in my opinion. @MikkoMarttila

Comment: Ah, fair enough -- for some reason I had it in my head that zoo was a recommended package, but evidently it's not. I'd still be weary with internal functions even if the usage pattern is clear, just because the API could be subject to change: The tidyr authors should be able to freely change/remove un-exported functions without breaking downstream code -- in a perfect world, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Fun little problem.  I've assumed the initial column1 only ever has 3 pieces.  Though, this can be extended by continuing the (c1, c2, c3) if not.

```
# Produce the initial cleaned tibble
df_joined <- df_joined %>% 
  mutate(column1 = str_remove_all(df_joined$column1, " ")) %>% 
  separate(column1, c("c1", "c2", "c3"), sep = ",") %>% # Increase if more than 3 parts in column1
  pivot_longer(-c(column2, column3), values_to = "column1") %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na() %>% 
  dplyr::relocate(column1)

 > head(df_joined)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  column1 column2 column3
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 ab34    ID_27   area51 
2 35      ID_27   area51 
3 36      ID_27   area51 
4 cb23    ID_28   area52 
5 df45    ID_29   area53 
6 46      ID_29   area53 

# Reproduce the characters for column1, where missing
df_joined <- df_joined %>% 
  mutate(prefix = str_sub(column1, 1, 2)) %>% 
  mutate(prefix = ifelse(str_detect(prefix, "[[:lower:]]") == TRUE, prefix, lag(prefix, 1))) %>%
  mutate(prefix = ifelse(str_detect(prefix, "[[:lower:]]") == TRUE, prefix, lag(prefix, 1))) %>% # iteration for multiple missing - Extend if some of the prefixes are missing
  mutate(column1 = str_remove_all(column1, "[[:lower:]]")) %>% 
  unite(col = "column1", c(prefix, column1), sep = "")

> head(df_joined)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  column1 column2 column3
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 ab34    ID_27   area51 
2 ab35    ID_27   area51 
3 ab36    ID_27   area51 
4 cb23    ID_28   area52 
5 df45    ID_29   area53 
6 df46    ID_29   area53
```

Comment: Nifty! For the first approach, reproducing the cleaned table, how do you cater for missing string values "" or NA values?

Comment: If you can give an example of where the empty strings or NAs will occur, then we can think of how to deal with them.  However, it's like that you'd change missing values into a dummy, and then run the rest.

Comment: I'll think about that. However, I've just noticed a slight problem. The output doesn't reproduce the two letter prefix for all the values in column1:

Comment: The first 3 rows are                                                                                                              1 ab34    ID_27   area51 
 2 35      ID_27   area51 
 3 36      ID_27   area51

Comment: They should be 1 ab34    ID_27   area51 
 2 ab35      ID_27   area51 
 3 ab36      ID_27   area51

Comment: Yes, adding the missing letters is the second piece of the code.  Outputs added to demonstrate.